# How to voxelize a height map?

Tags: blender, voxels, minecraft-modding, unreal

Lets say I make a height map and I want to make it out of CUBES to use in my game. I dont want to generate anything procedualy, I just want to cubify a height map. So I just want a static mesh.
I also want to LOD it, so I have a 1024 version, a 512 version, and a 256 version.
Btw I am using Blender and UE4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure goes something like this:

```
for(x = 0; x < worldSize; x += cubeSize)
  for(y = 0; y < worldSize; y += cubeSize)
      float mapX = (x/worldSize) * mapSize
      float mapY = (y/worldSize) * mapSize
      float height = heightMap.GetValue(mapX, mapY)
      for(z = 0; z < height; z+= cubeSize)
          PlaceCube(x,y,z)
```

Essentially, you iterate through your world, mapping a world location to a height map location. Then you create a column of cubes as high as the height map value at that location.

From there, things get complicated. If you want to hide cubes that are hidden by surrounding terrain (as most of the columns will be), you need to check their orthogonal surroundings before placing them. And there are optimizations. For example, the final loop can start at the terrain height, and once you reach a cube that's not visible, you stop processing cubes for that column. Being a height map, you can make a lot of useful assumptions about what's going to be visible later on. If one cube in a column is not visible, none of the cubes below it are going to be visible either.